# Android Radio Button Bug

Tags: java, android, firebase

Database Structure:
[image: Database Structure:]

So I have been working on a project and I have applied radio buttons and now, I want to modify data in my FireStore Cloud Database but due to some bug, I am not able to go through the IF STATEMENT.
Please help me out!
Thank you so much!!

```
        private RadioGroup radioGroup;
        private RadioButton type;
```

```
        redeemButton = findViewById(R.id.redeem_button);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        redeemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                type = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Bank").document(name);
                if ((type.getText()) == "Maalish")
```

Probably the problem code(Edit):

```
if ((type.getText()) == "Maalish")
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I have added the database structure

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see any structure of your database.

Comment: Alex Mamo, I haved added it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
if (type.getText().toString().equals("Maalish"))
```